# Playing MP3/AAC music on powered loudspeaker

Tags: mp3, preamp, line-level, loudspeakers

I have a Mackie Thump15 15-Inch powered loudspeaker that I want to be able to play music from my iTunes library on. The speaker has active amplification and has a mic and line input. I read that I can simply plug my iPhone or Mac headphone jack into the line input with the volume turned way down, but because of the amplification of the headphone jack, the quality would be less than that of using a less amplified line input. I have looked into preamps that allow MP3 or usb input, but I know very little about this and I'm not sure I can make an educated decision on my own. I have endless computing resources I could use to connect to the speaker, but the problem is I'm not sure how, or what is the best way. I am not a DJ, so I would have no use for mixers and DJ software. I would prefer a high quality solution, but I also don't want to spend too much money to do it.

Edits:
As it stands I currently have one speaker. However, in the future I may eventually get another, but that is a long ways off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the output from your iPhone or Mac is likely stereo. Do you have TWO of these speakers?  Or do you want to combine the Left + Right signals together into a monaural signal?  You will need some way to combine the Left + Right signals together if you have only one speaker.

There will be no significany "loss of quality" feeding the headphone output from a modern device into the line-level input of audio gear like your speaker.

EDIT: There are apparently commercial products available that will do exactly what you need.  Here is an example of a perfect solution...

> Great for connecting iPhone, iPad, or any 3.5mm audio output to a powered speaker
>   Combines 3.5mm Left and Right Channels Into XLR Single Mono Feed (See Diagram)

[https://www.amazon.com/GLS-Audio-Cable-Stereo-Male/dp/B006LRPF7Y](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006LRPF7Y)

Comment: I have made edits to my original post in regards to your question.